# Java Regex to keep character but only when used inside expression

Tags: java, regex

Example: This is a text [Java [Script]] [Programming]

Expected output:

1. group 1: Java [Script]
2. group 2: Programming

What I tried: `\[([^\[\]]*?)\]` which gives me two groups but the groups are:

1. group 1: Script
2. group 2: Programming

Group 1 is wrong since it should be Java [Script].

The question is how can I skip the [] at the beginning and end but still count them if they are inside [] and keep every character inside?

Comment: I don't think regex can do what you want. I think you need to use a parser.

Comment: And I don't get how "group 2: Programming language" came up in the results with this code.

Comment: What is the logic here? Do you want balanced square brackets? What if you have `[test[Java [Script]]test]` ?

Comment: @Thefourthbird. Yes, in your case the group would be `test[Java [Script]]test` . Just the surrounding `[` `]` would be skipped.

Comment: And there should be no match for `test[Java [Script]]]test` ?

Comment: You're basically looking for a 1-deep balanced delimiter parser, which is a word vomit way of saying "parsing a string, grabbing everything between some left `(` and right `)`". Regex is mathematically the wrong tool for this, and while every regex engine has [some kind of hack to make it sort-of work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses), it can be ugly or brittle or both. The basic idea with a parser is to iterate through the string, count how "deep" into your braces you are, and to return strings when you change a certain amount (1->0)

Comment: @Thefourthbird No match for what's inside the the first surrounding [ ]

Comment: I wanted to use regex because Iin the end I want to replace all the found groups with something else which would only be 1 line of code.

Comment: It doesn't have to be regex for that either. When you know where a sequence of letters starts and ends which has to be replaced by something else you can split the string at those places and stitch it together with the desired "filler". When this is your goal, with what do you want to replace them with?

Comment: Wait. Is it always a pair?

Comment: @ValerijDobler it can be as many [] as possible. Not just 2. That was my example.

Comment: @Raz, but still what is the goal? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Raz you could write a parser, and then using that parser would be `String replaced = parser.parse(String)`, which is 1 line. In fact, encapsulation is a core principal of OOP, and that's basically what you'd be doing here (encapsulating the ugly multiline logic behind a parser, which will solve it elsewheres in 1 line). The actual parsing code is effectively 5-10 lines.

Comment: @Rogue I'm eager seeing the parser. Do you mind appending an answer with the impl?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a direct approach, where the provided `#parse` method can be integrated however you like into your application:

```
private static List<String> parse(String input, String prefix, String suffix) {
    int depth = 0; //how deeply nested we are in the delimiters
    int left = -1; //a marker variable for substring-ing groups at depth==1 
    List<String> back = new ArrayList<>(); //our observed groups at depth==1
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length();) { //iterate the string char-by-char for groups
        if (input.startsWith(prefix, i)) {
            //we found an opening delimiter for a group, depth increases
            depth++;
            i += prefix.length(); //skip delimiter
            if (depth == 1) {
                //mark the position for our substring when depth goes from 0->1
                left = i;
            }
        } else if (depth > 0 && input.startsWith(suffix, i)) {
            // we found a closing delimiter for a group
            // depth>0 to ignore suffix outside of balanced group
            if (depth == 1) {
                //substring out the result when depth goes 1->0
                back.add(input.substring(left, i));
            }
            depth--;
            i += suffix.length(); //skip delimiter
        } else {
            i++; //forward iteration until we find a prefix or suffix
        }
    }
    return back;
}

private static List<String> parseBrackets(String input) {
    return parse(input, "[", "]");
}
```

As you can see, the usage is only a single line:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Content of `tags`: ["Java [Script]", "Programming"]
    List<String> tags = parseBrackets("This is a text [Java [Script]] [Programming]");
}
```

The overall performance of this approach is `O(n)`, and will be roughly on par to solutions utilizing `String#indexOf` or a regex pattern (likely outperforming the latter). This really leaves the question of how you fit it into your design in a way that makes sense. No state is needed to be maintained, so you could very well leave it as a static utility method. Overall, this is the work that would occur in the background of essentially any parser (some form of abstract state machine operating on the input character-by-character).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an oneliner using [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) with [recursive pattern](https://github.com/florianingerl/com.florianingerl.util.regex?tab=readme-ov-file#recursive-regular-expressions) which are sadly not part of the `java.util.regex` API, **BUT** can be used through the inclusion of third-party libraries like [java.pcre](https://github.com/raimonbosch/java.pcre) or [JRegex](https://jregex.sourceforge.net/index.html)

`(?:\[)((?:[^\]\[]+|(?R))*+)(?:\])`

Bisection:

```
(?:\[)                  # non-capturing group of outer starting square bracket
      (                 # start of main capturing group
       (?:              # start non-capturing inner group
          [^\]\[]+      # a literal set of the tokens which are neither [ nor ]
           |            # or
          (?R)          # sub routine - matching the entire pattern
       )*+              # possessive greedy matching of 0 or more times the non-capturing inner group
      )                 # end of main capturing group
(?:\])                  # non-capturing group of outer ending square bracket
```

resulting in

```bash
Match 1 = Java [Script]
Match 2 = Programming
```